# I am unable to create a new NLog Logger because of 'Logger.Logger()'s protection level

Tags: c#, wpf, logging, prism, nlog

I am currently working on a new Prism project in C# and wanted to create an NLog Logger in my Bootstrapper class. Unfortunately, no matter what I do it refuses to build, telling me...

> 'Logger.Logger()' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

The fragment of my code in question is listed below...

```
namespace PrismTemplate
{

    public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
    {
        #region Method Overrides

        protected override ILoggerFacade CreateLogger()
        {
            //ILoggerFacade logger = new NLogLogger();
            ILoggerFacade logger = new Logger();
            logger.Log("Prism Template Logger was Created.", Category.Info, Priority.None);
            return logger;

            //return new Logger();
            //return null;
        }

        protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            return new ShellWindow();
        }

        protected override void InitializeShell()
        {
            base.InitializeShell();

            ///Assign the shell which is a window to the apps main window, and show it

            App.Current.MainWindow = (Window)this.Shell;
            App.Current.MainWindow.Show();

        }

        #endregion Method Overrides

    }
}
```

I downloaded both Prism and NLog via Nuget in Visual Studio. Any help attacking this problem would be most appreciated.

Thanks,

Tesnich

Comment: You don't normally instantiate loggers directly, you get them from `LogManager`  For example: `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` or `LogManager.GetLogger("classname")`

Answer (score 5):

Due to the heavy configuration of loggers, NLog has chosen to delegate the log creation responsibility to the sealed LogManager class.

You can use either to get an instance:

`LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()`

or

`LogManager.GetLogger(string name)`

Comment: Also caching is there is the logmanager, to prevent unneeded memory/CPU usage.